# Apple Wallet passes comperation

Tags: ios, wallet

I have a loyalty programm app where every user can add his loyalty card in Wallet. Each of cards have same `passTypeIdentifier` and `serialNumber` but different barcode information.  When I already have a card in Wallet and trying to add new card for new user `containsPass` method of `PKPassLibrary` returns true. How can I correctly compare these two cards? I can suggest to add field with unique id to `backingFields` (card number for example), but maybe you have better solution

Answer (score 0):

Your passes should not have the same serial number.  From the [*PassKit Package Format Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW2)

> `serialNumber` - Serial number that uniquely identifies the pass. No two passes with the same pass type identifier may have the same serial number.

The serial number would typically be the same as the barcode number, or at least related to it in some way.